# Get Table Value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dovecot</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.10</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dpsel</td>
    <td>dps-e-learn.in</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.06</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>svarun</td>
    <td>svarun.in</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.02</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>DELAYED</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hostc1</td>
    <td>hostraptor.in</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.05</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Top Process</td>
    <td>%CPU 0.1</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      httpd [ecomwel.hostraptor.in] [/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php?gid7]
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>astrore</td>
    <td>astroreddy.com</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.02</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cpanel</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>named</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.20</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a table like above I need to search in that table with a name dynamically using jQuery

For eg : I need to search using astrore and I need to get the next element I mean I need to get this domain name...

and this `tr td` will be changed every 2 min...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows for a repeating check for the value:

```
function scanForValue(value) {
    $("td").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text()==value) {
            console.log($(this).next().text());
        }
    });

    window.setTimeout("scanForValue('"+value+"');", 120000);
}

scanForValue('astrore');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLKRd/3/

Comment: You're welcome, I've been trying to get one right for a long time now :)

Comment: this is not working .. ? 
    window.setTimeout("scanForValue('"+value+"');", 10);

Answer (score 4):

The [contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
var value = $("td:contains('astrore')").next().text();
```